# Dificuldade com loops para jogo da memória

Tags: c++

O programa refere-se a um jogo da memória composto por 3 matrizes 4x4, onde o jogador está contra o programa. A minha dificuldade está quanto a ação do programa nos casos em que o jogador acerta o par de números, pois pretendo deixar a matriz com os números revelados "impressos" na tela e iniciar a próxima jogada e nos casos em que ele erra, pois então quem joga seria o computador e após retornaria para jogador.

Os critérios são esse;

Composto por 16 peças, caractere ou número (8 pares, 4x4);

Haverá apenas um jogador jogando “contra o programa”;

A cada novo jogo a posição das peças deve estar em locais diferentes. Para isso, podem ser geradas 3 matrizes e selecionada uma diferente a cada novo jogo;

Em cada jogada, o jogador informa a posição (linha e coluna) das peças a serem mostradas;

O programa deve mostrar o valor destas peças. Caso as peças tenham o mesmo valor, estas ficam indisponíveis e aparece a mensagem “JOGADA OK”. Caso contrário, aparece a mensagem “JOGADA NOK”;

O jogador pode fazer 24 jogadas;

O jogo encerra quando o jogador encerrar o número de jogadas ou até ele descobrir todos os pares;

No encerramento deve ser apresentada a opção para o jogador jogar novamente ou sair;

Não utilize variáveis globais;

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

int cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, cpu4;
int ti=2, tm=2, i, j, p1, p2, p3, p4, tent=24;
int mz[4][4]={0}, ma1[4][4]={1,4,5,7,2,5,8,2,6,3,4,3,7,1,8,6};

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

srand(time(NULL));
//abaixo a parte do código que tenho dificuldade

cout << "\t" << "1° COORDENADA" << "\n";//pedido das coordenadas 1
cout << "\n" << "N° da Linha: ";
cin >> p1;
cout << "\n" << "N° da Coluna: ";
cin >> p2;
cout << "\n";

for(i=0;i<4;i++){//laço para a matriz com o primeiro numero
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(p1 == i && p2 == j){
            cout << ma1[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        else if(p1<0 || p1>3 || p2<0 || p2>3){
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            cout << mz[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

cout << "\n\t" << "2° COORDENADA" << "\n";//pedido da coordenada 2
cout << "\n" << "N° da Linha: ";
cin >> p3;
cout << "\n" << "N° da Coluna: ";
cin >> p4;
cout << "\n";

for(i=0;i<4;i++){//laço com os dois números na matriz
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        if(p1 == i && p2 == j){
            cout << ma1[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        else if(p3 == i && p4 == j){
            cout << ma1[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        else if(p3 == p1 && p4 == p2){
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(p3<0 || p3>3 || p4<0 || p4>3){
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            cout << mz[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

//aqui inicia a verificação se o jogador errou ou acertou
//como pode-se ver só tem o caso se ele erra e passa a vez
//preciso saber como posso montar no caso que ele acerta

    if(ma1[p1][p2] != ma1[p3][p4]){
    tent--;

    cout << "\n" << "Você errou, lhe restam (" << tent << ") tentativas.";
    cout << "\n" << "CPU irá jogar agora!";

    Sleep(5000);
    system("cls");

    cout << "Eu escolho..." << "\n\n";
    cpu1 = rand() % 4;
    cpu2 = rand() % 4;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(i == cpu1 && j == cpu2){
                cout << ma1[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            else{
                cout << mz[i][j] << "\t";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    Sleep(3000);

    cout << "\n" << "E também..." << "\n\n";
    start1:
    cpu3 = rand() % 4;
    cpu4 = rand() % 4;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(i == cpu3 && j == cpu4){
                cout << ma1[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            else if(i == cpu1 && j == cpu2){
                cout << ma1[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            else if(cpu1 == cpu3 && cpu2 == cpu4){
                goto start1;
            }
            else{
                cout << mz[i][j] << "\t";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
//ambas situações verificam apenas
//se o jogador e a cpu erraram, quero saber continuar o codigo
//quando eles acertam a coordenada.
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Importante ler o material indicado no comentário anterior, e depois [edit] o post fornecendo um [mcve] só da parte com problema, e uma explicação do que está com dificuldade exatamente, de maneira bem clara.